# How come my event.currentTarget is changing automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

Please have a look at the code below.

```
function deferredClick(f) {
    return (function (e) {
        var $this = $(e.currentTarget);
        console.log('Actual target: ', e.currentTarget);

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('Target I get here: ', e.currentTarget);
            f.call($this.get(0), e);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function clickResponder(e) {
    var $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    $("#out").html('Clicked - ' + $this.val());
}

$('input[type="button"]').on('vclick', deferredClick(clickResponder));
```

The idea is to trigger the event handler after some fixed delay. When you run the above code, you will get two logs in console. [JSFiddle demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/D7GTP/ ]

```
Actual target: <input class="ui-btn-hidden" type="button" value="click me" data-disabled="false">
Target I get here: Document
```

How come `e.currentTarget` is mutating from line 4 to line 7?

**Please note:** The event in question is `vclick`, which is provided by jquerymobile.

Comment: e.currentTarget isn't changing, e is

Comment: If `$this` is still the same then why would `e` change?

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bJzWj/6/

Comment: @ArunPJohny What are you trying to demonstrate from your demo?

Comment: See also [event currentTarget changes after setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39649156/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How come `e.currentTarget` is mutating from line 4 to line 7?

Because of event bubbling. There is only one event object which is passed to all registered handlers down from the `<input>` up to the `document`. On every stage, the `currentTarget` property is changed to the current target element. After the event left the `document`, it will be set to `null`.

Yet, the situation is a littlebit different for you. You've got jQuery and jQueryMobile loaded, which add their own event stuff each. jQuery for example [constructs normalized `Event` objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), and it seems Mobile adds another extra layer. You can try to inspect the `.originalEvent` property.

Why is that different now? The custom event construction happens on every stage, and your listener gets a unique object. It's `currentTarget` does not change. You can observe this when you use the normal `click` event. Yet, if you use the Mobile's `vclick` event then event delegation will be used. Here, the custom event object gets reused. When it fires your handler, the `currentTarget` gets set to the `<input>`. After that, it gets reset to the element where the delegation was bound to - the `document`.

When you log the properties in the timeout, you will get those from after all the modifications - not those that were relevant to you. The same thing happens when you `console.log` the event object (see [lazy logging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440)).

### TL;DR:

When you access the event properties during the execution of your callback, you can expect them to be accurate.

When you access the event properties *after* the handlers were triggered, then if you're using

- plain DOM events: the `currentTarget` will be `null`
- jQuery events: the `currentTarget` will stay the same
- jQuery delegated events (including jQueryMobile ones): the `currentTarget` will be the actual bound target