# Why does e.currentTarget object become null after awaited promise function call or then method of a promise in JavaScript/Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to reset its field of a form after an async function completes execution. However, when the async function completes its instructions, I found that the e.currentTarget (where e is the React.FormEvent<HtmlFormElement> object). Here is the code please review and let me know what was wrong in my code:

```java
onAddFormSubmitted(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): Promise<void> {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formdata = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

  // e.currentTarget.reset(); // it worked here

  if (formdata) {
    const book: Book = {
      title: formdata.get("booktitle") as string,
      author: formdata.get("authorname") as string,
    }

    addBook(book).then((doc) => {
        book.id = doc.id;
        this.props.onBookCreated(book);
        e.currentTarget.reset(); // e.currentTarget becoming null at this point. Why?
      });
    }
  }
```

I am trying to reset form element after the asynchronous function call. But, the currentTarget object becomes null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come my event.currentTarget is changing automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607766/how-come-my-event-currenttarget-is-changing-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the desired target:

```js
onAddFormSubmitted(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): Promise<void> {
  e.preventDefault();
  const currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
  const formdata = new FormData(currentTarget);

  if (formdata) {
    const book: Book = {
      title: formdata.get("booktitle") as string,
      author: formdata.get("authorname") as string,
    }

    addBook(book).then((doc) => {
        book.id = doc.id;
        this.props.onBookCreated(book);
        currentTarget.reset(); // e.currentTarget becoming null at this point. Why?
      });
    }
  }
```

The same event object is used throughout the capturing and bubbling phases and `currentTarget` is updated on each step. Once bubbling is complete, `currentTarget` is set to `null`. Your async code executes after bubbling.

This is how native events work in the DOM, this is not related to React.

See also [How come my event.currentTarget is changing automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607766/how-come-my-event-currenttarget-is-changing-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

i have also stumbled upon this and have not many ideas. capturing it before the async operation seemed to work.

```
  async function submitForm(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { currentTarget } = e;

    const resetable = currentTarget;

    const formData = new FormData(currentTarget);

    await upload(formData);

    resetable.reset();
  }
```